# AutoQuery: join tables via a middle table and define which FK to join on

Tags: servicestack, ormlite-servicestack, autoquery-servicestack

We started using ServiceStack AutoQuery recently. It's a nice feature and we really enjoyed it. We have a table structure like this (minified version to make it easy to read):

```
Salary [Id (PK), ManagerId (FK)] 
Manager [Id (PK), DepartmentId (FK)] /* Manager is like Employee table even thought it's named Manager */
Department [Id (PK), ActiveManagerId (FK)] /* The FK ActiveManagerId is supposed to be a shortcut, it's Nullable.  */
```

So theoretically we can have joins like so

```
Salary -> Manager via Salary.ManagerId = Manager.Id
Manager -> Department via Manager.DepartmentId = Department.Id
Department -> Manager via Department.ActiveManagerId = Manager.Id
```

However in this specific case, if we join from Department to Manager via Department.ActiveManagerId = Manager.Id will not produce correct results because Department.ActiveManagerId is a shortcut and designed for other scenarios.

So when I define AutoQuery like so

```
public class SalaryQuery : QueryBase<Salary, SalaryQueryResult>,
 ILeftJoin<Salary, Manager, Department>
```

Below SQL is produced by AutoQuery which is correct from ServiceStack AutoQuery perspective.

```
select  s.Id
    ,   d.Id
from    Salary s
    left join
        Manager m
    on  s.ManagerId = m.Id
    left join
        Department d
    on  d.ActiveManagerId = m.Id /* should NOT use shortcut: Department -> Manager via Department.ActiveManagerId = Manager.Id */
```

But instead we want the ability to produce SQL which looks like this

```
select  s.Id
    ,   d.Id
from    Salary s
    left join
        Manager m
    on  s.ManagerId = m.id
    left join
        Department d
    on  d.Id = m.DepartmentId /* should use the desired FK: Manager -> Department via Manager.DepartmentId = Department.Id */
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want different JOIN behavior you would need to add the custom LEFT JOIN in a [Custom AutoQuery implementation](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/AutoQuery-RDBMS#custom-autoquery-implementations), e.g:

```
//AutoQuery DTO
public class SalaryQuery : QueryDb<Salary,SalaryQueryResult>, ILeftJoin<Salary,Manager>

//Implementation
public class MyServices : Service
{
    public IAutoQueryDb AutoQuery { get; set; }

    public object Any(SalaryQuery query)
    {
        var q = AutoQuery.CreateQuery(query, base.Request)
            .LeftJoin<Manager, Department>((m, d) => d.Id == m.DepartmentId);

        return AutoQuery.Execute(query, q);
    } 
}
```

> Note: From v4.0.56 `QueryBase<T>` has been [deprecated and renamed to QueryDb](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/docs/2016/v4.0.56.md#autoquery-breaking-changes).

Comment: I was hoping there would be some kind of attribute to let me manually define the join ON so that it saves me from having to write the manual Service implementation. Ok. I'll do the suggested way. Thanks @mythz.

Comment: I believe there might be a bug in AQ (i.e. being too flexible).
If I have ForeignKey attribute declared on Department.ActiveManagerId in C#, the produced sql will join ON (d.ActiveManagerId = m.Id) - 1st sql in original question, however if I remove ForeignKey on Department.ActiveManagerId, the sql produced will join ON (d.Id = m.DepartmentId) - 2nd sql in original question. Because Manager.DepartmentId (in C#) also has the ForeignKey attribute declared. So why would AQ produce different join ON when the join declaration stays the same (i.e.  ILeftJoin<Salary, Manager, Department>)?

Comment: @Jeff Because the [ForeignKey and References attributes has precedence for defining references](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite#foreign-key-and-references-attributes).

Comment: Example 1:

public class Manager {
 [ForeignKey(typeof(Department))]
 public Guid DepartmentId {get;set;}
}
public class Department {
 [ForeignKey(typeof(Department), OnDelete = "SET NULL")]
 public Guid ActiveManagerId {get;set;}
}

which generates join on d.ActiveManagerId = m.Id (RHS.FKId = LHS.Id)

Comment: Example 2:
public class Manager {
 [ForeignKey(typeof(Department))]
 public Guid DepartmentId {get;set;}
}
public class Department {
//Removed FK attribute here
 public Guid ActiveManagerId {get;set;}
}

generates join on d.Id = m.DepartmentId (RHS.Id = LHS.FKId)

Comment: By RHS/LHS I mean the orders which the tables are defined in ILeftJoin<MainTable, LHS, RHS>.

So shouldn't example 2 produce some kind of exception because AQ can't find the mapping FK either by attribute or by convention from Department?

Sorry for the multiple comments.

Comment: @Jeff Not sure what's being disputed, in the absence of attributes it falls back to the [implicit reference conventions](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite#reference-conventions) of `Department.Id = Manager.DepartmentId`.

Comment: I'm saying if I write ILeftJoin<Salary, Manager, Department>, I should expact the join to be on Department.ActiveManagerId = Manager.Id (D -> M). It should never be Department.Id = Manager.DepartmentId (M -> D). I am saying the orders defined in ILeftJoin should matter, the order should determine which table to pick the FK from. But I guess from AQ perspective, it's just trying to figure out whether there's a convention and / or whether there's an attribute FK/Reference so the orders defined in ILeftJoin shouldn't matter. I see what you are saying, the orders shouldn't matter at all.

Comment: And I guess having bi-directional design in the first place was what caused all the shebang.